# Non-invertible linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show the composition $S\circ T$ with $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and $S:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is noninvertible. What would be the best way to show this since I don't believe it's sufficient to just say since $S$ and $T$ aren't invertible, $S\circ T$ isn't invertible.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $S \circ T$ can't be invertible if its kernel is nontrivial. By rank-nullity, can $\ker T$ be trivial?

Answer (score 1):

$\text{Im}(T)\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\text{rank}(T)\le 2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\text{rank}(S\circ T)\le 2<3$ $\Rightarrow$ not invertible.